# Setting up a local git repository on Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu

I'm trying to setup a Git repo on my local machine for work that is being done on my local machine - no remote anything.

I've setup remote repos several times but it seems the steps I take locally always end up with errors.

I have 2 directories:  `/home/rico/project` and `/home/git/project_repo`

I've created the git user to manage all my git repos (I expect to have dozens).

From `/home/rico/project` as the `rico` user I do the following command:

```
rico@verbal:~/project$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/rico/project/.git/
```

From `/home/git/project_repo` as the `git` user I do the following:

```
git@verbal:~/project_repo$ git --bare init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/git/project_repo
```

Now I go back to my project and add files.

```
rico@verbal:~/project$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       .project
#       .pydevproject
#       inc/
#       manage.py
#       rocksolidbox/
#       rsb/
#       templates/
rico@verbal:~/project$ git add inc media rocksolidbox/ rsb/ templates/
rico@verbal:~/project$ git commit -a -m "Initialize the project."
```

At this point I get the normal commit message - `23 files changed, 989 insertions(+)` etc.

Now, I want to push this to the `project_repo` folder.

```
rico@verbal:~/project$ git remote add origin /home/git/rocksolidbox/
rico@verbal:~/project$ git push -u /home/git/rocksolidbox/ master
```

But receive the following error:

```
Counting objects: 31, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (26/26), done.
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects

fatal: failed to write object
Writing objects: 100% (31/31), 12.24 KiB, done.
Total 31 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To /home/git/project_repo/
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (n/a (unpacker error))
error: failed to push some refs to '/home/git/project_repo/'
```

Clearly this is a permissions error.  I've tried to do the push such as:

```
rico@verbal:~/project$ git push -u git@verbal:/home/git/rocksolidbox/ master
```

Or even using my local IP:

```
rico@verbal:~/project$ git push -u git@192.168.1.101:/home/git/rocksolidbox/ master
```

It asks for a password, which I know I'm supplying correctly and I continually get the message `Permission denied, please try again.`

I just want to be able to push my `project` to my `project_repo`.  What am I doing wrong in this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've figured out a way around the permissions problem.  Basically do this:

```
git@verbal:~/$ chmod -R 777 project_repo
```

Then I can do the following commands with my `project`:

```
rico@verbal:~/project$ git remote add origin /home/git/project_repo/
rico@verbal:~/project$ git push -u /home/git/project_repo/ master
```

Then to clone the project elsewhere simply do:

```
rico@verbal:~/some_other_location$ git clone /home/git/project_repo
```

And you're golden.

Now, my question remains...is this the best way of handling the permissions problem?  I don't really like the idea of giving `777` to anything.  Should I put `git` and `rico` in the same group and do `775` instead?

Any suggestions?

EDIT1:
Putting `git` and `rico` in the same group and doing `775` did not help.  It works fine with `777` but I don't like this solution.

Comment: Are you expecting someone else to push to your repo? If not, there's no point in making the bare-repo under a different user. Generally the pattern you've done (having your own user and a `git` user) is used for team environments where you don't want to give others access to your own personal account. It is important if you do this to make sure you keep your users straight when issuing commands... `rico` should only issue commands on the non-bare repo and `git` should only issue commands on the bare repo. Otherwise the file permissions _will_ change when you do a push or pull.

Comment: I will be working with a team.  So, how do I push from `rico@verbal:~/project` to the bare repo without having `777` on the bare repo?

Answer (score 1):

Don't do all that fancy permissions footwork. You want [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite).

Comment: That documentation isn't very good.  `**NOTE**: if you are asked for a password, something has gone wrong.` Ok...so what went wrong and how do I fix it?  I'm not impressed so far.

Comment: @Rico Try the instructions in http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Gitolite .

Comment: @echristopherson Sorry, but even those instructions are very poor.  I can't even get past the command in the `installation` section.  `This is essential for the install script, so check to make sure you can run a command without getting a password prompt:`  They never talk about how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck at the same point. "Something has gone wrong" isn't very informative so far. After comparing dozens of "it's a piece of cake"-titled howtos I figured out the main problem. Most of the examples have client and server on the same host. That's not what I wanted. After editing the ~/.ssh/config the way shown below it worked like a charm.

For this example the server host is known as **gitolite**, the special account for installing gitolite on the server is called **git**, the user on the client is named **harrie** and the keypair in /home/harrie/.ssh has been generated by "ssh-keygen-t rsa -f harrie".

~/.ssh/config

```
Host gitolite
        User git
        Hostname gitolite
        Port 22
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/harrie
```